# Placeholder.FindControl() only identifying the first control in placeholder and NULL returns for other controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder

I am developing a website by using ASP.NET.
I have a placeholder to dynamically show controls.
Here is my ASPX code for that.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="pHolderTest"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

From code behind I use this code to generate controls inside placeholder.

```
        RadioButton rdbTest1 = new RadioButton() { Text = "&nbsp Test1", GroupName = "my", ID = "rdbTest1", Checked = true };
        pHolderTest.Controls.Add(rdbTest1 );
        pHolderTest.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "</br>" });

        RadioButton rdbTest2  = new RadioButton() { Text = "&nbsp Test2", GroupName = "my", ID = "rdbTest2" };
        pHolderTest.Controls.Add(rdbTest2);
        pHolderTest.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "</br>" });

        //----So on
```

So when a user select a particular radiobutton in this placeholder I want to get what user is clicked. So to do that I used this code.

```
 RadioButton rdbTest1 = pHolderTest.FindControl("rdbTest1") as RadioButton;
 RadioButton rdbTest2 = pHolderTest.FindControl("rdbTest2") as RadioButton;

 if (rdbTest1.Checked)
 {
 //--Code
 }
 else if (rdbTest2.Checked)
 {
 //--Code
 }
```

So everythings ok. But probelem is When I findcontrols inside placeholder It only getting the first radiobutton (rdbTest1) and after that other controls getting NULL values. I am calling to my dynamic controls generating function on Page_Load event to retain my Placeholder when every PostBack. I am only getting the value of the first radiobutton. So how to find my all controls inside the placeholder?

Comment: You have to specify when in ASP.NET's Page Life-cycle your codes are running.  Assuming you are adding the dynamic controls on the Placeholder during Page Load, are the controls still there during post back?  When are you executing the FindControl calls?

Comment: In ASP.Net, dynamically created controls must be re-created at Page_Init in order to exist. When you create them at this stage, the page lifecycle will bind the viewstate and will be ready for use.

Comment: I am calling to that function at pageLoad event. As I told you I am getting the value for the first radio button...Others are NULL.So its mean that MyPlaceholder is there right?